# Calling several synchronous services with RxJS + Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm currently doing a small Angular app that will retrieve some employee info with REST calls. However, I got stuck while handling a request similar to `api/department/:departmentId/employee/:employeeId`. Here's the thing: On `ngOnInit()`, I know I need to call the DepartmentService first and then use its result to query stuff on the EmployeeService. Based on the Angular tutorial, I would normally do this with one parameter:

```
this.router.params.switchMap((params: Params) =>
  this.employeeService.getEmployee(+params['employeeId'])).subscribe(employee => {
    this.employee = employee;
  }
);
```

I've tried this, for example:

```
this.router.params.switchMap((params: Params) =>
  this.departmentService.getDepartmentById(+params['id'])).subscribe(department => {
    this.department = department;
    this.router.params.switchMap((params: Params) =>
      this.employeeService.getEmployee(+params['employeeId'])).subscribe(employee => {
        this.currentEmployee = employee;
        this.equipment = this.currentEmployee.equipments.find(eq => {
          return eq.employeeId === this.currentEmployee.id && eq.departmentId === this.department.id;
        });
      }
    );
  }
);
```

I'm not sure what's the preferred way to chain calls using Params. I've read about Defer and BindCallback, but I haven't been able to implement either successfully. Keep in mind that I would need the results from both services so that child components can use them for rendering, and preferrably handle errors from both calls (eventually they will be network calls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove at least one `subscribe`:

```
this.route.params
    .do((params: Params) => this.params = params)
    .switchMap(() => this.departmentService.getDepartmentById(+this.params['id']))
    .do((department) => this.department = department)
    .switchMap(department => this.employeeService.getEmployee(+this.params['employeeId']))
    .subscribe(employee => {
        this.currentEmployee = employee;
        this.equipment = this.currentEmployee.equipments.find(eq => {
            return eq.employeeId === this.currentEmployee.id && eq.departmentId === this.department.id;
        });
    });
```

It can be simplified more using `route.snapshot.params`:

```
this.departmentService
    .getDepartmentById(+this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
    .do((department) => this.department = department)
    .switchMap(department => this.employeeService.getEmployee(+this.route.snapshot.params['employeeId']))
    .subscribe(employee => {
        this.currentEmployee = employee;
        this.equipment = this.currentEmployee.equipments.find(eq => {
            return eq.employeeId === this.currentEmployee.id && eq.departmentId === this.department.id;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Couldn't implement the simplified version, getDepartmentById returns a Promise. First version turned out just fine!

Comment: There is also an option to use Observable.fromPromise(getDepartmentById(...))